# Aggregating by Dimensions

Tags: tableau-api

So recently a database update caused what used to be 2 fields to become a new table. As a result, our inventory tracking system has gone from looking like this:

```
Item | Old Count | New Count | Difference
A    | 2         | 4         | 2
B    | 5         | 3         | -2
C    | 0         | 1         | 1
```

To this (after a table join):

```
Item | Action    | Quantity
A    | Current   | 2         
A    | Add       | 2         
B    | Current   | 5
B    | Remove    | 1
B    | Remove    | 1
C    | Current   | 0
C    | Add       | 3
C    | Remove    | 2
```

I'd like to be able to create Calculated Fields to condense all this new information back into the format from the original example, but can't seem to figure out how outside of SQL.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did with four calc fields.

create old count: `if [Action] = 'current' then [Quantity] end`

create hold: `if [Action] = 'add' then [Quantity]
elseif [Action] = 'remove' then -[Quantity] end`

create new count: `sum([hold])+sum([old count])`
create diff: `[new count]-sum([old count])`

then I placed them on the rows and columns like your sample. See attached workbook https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/160316%20stack%20question.twbx

Comment: Cheers, thanks a lot! I think this should work for what I'm doing. I thought for whatever reason it wouldn't calculate properly in more complex dashboards, I don't suppose there's any reason why it shouldn't since I'm always rolling up to Item or Item Category (parent object).